# Looking for preprocessor command to remove command in code

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, bcc-compiler

I am working on a C library which sometimes uses

```
 static inline void myfunc(...)
```

when defining a function.

Now I try to port this to an old C compiler that does not support "static inline". This is bcc - Bruce's C compiler.

Can I use a command in a header file that replaces

```
static inline void
```

with

```
void
```

in all programs that include this header file?

Comment: I think you could add an empty definition of void: #define void.

Comment: Are you sure you want to redefine the `void` keyword and not the `inline` keyword? Also look search for and read about *conditional compilation*.

Comment: Sorry this was a typo - I want to replace "static inline void" with "void"

Answer (score 5):

When you must target a compiler that does not support certain features, it is common to use macros in your code, rather than trying to modify your code with macros.

In this situation you can define `STATIC_INLINE` macro in a compiler-dependent way, and use it like this:

```
#ifdef BCC_COMPILER
#define STATIC_INLINE
#else
#define STATIC_INLINE static inline
#endif
...
STATIC_INLINE void myfunc(...)
```

Comment: This will work, but I already have so many ifdef's in the code. I hoped it would be shorter to define this in one place with a #define command or similar.

Comment: I now understand, yes you can put this code into the header file. Is it possible to get the preprocessor to replace "static inline" with an empty string? Then I do not have to change every program code.

Comment: @Georg Unfortunately, preprocessor can replace a single token, not a pair of tokens that appear next to each other. That's why many libraries I've seen use this trick, even though it makes the rest of the code less readable.

Comment: Do you really want to lose the `static` from `static inline`?  You're suddenly exposing all the functions and liable to get multiple definition errors.  If the compiler doesn't support `inline`, `#define inline /*nothing*/` might be better.  (Of course, if the functions that were previously `static inline` are now just `static` but aren't used, you might get warnings about unused functions instead — or suffer code bloat because of them, or both.)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much to all for the help. I have to report that [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) gave the answer that worked for me in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415760/looking-for-preprocessor-command-to-remove-command-in-code#comment70035839_41415760):

```
 #define inline
```

Apparently bcc does accept `static void` but not `static inline void`.

Comment: A simpler way of expressing that would be 'Bcc does not support `inline` functions'.  The support for `static` and `void` is required even in C90 compilers; `inline` was added to C99.